# how to set value to observable item of observable Array in knockout js

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have a observable array of observable items as below:

```
self.textboxArray = ko.observableArray();

for (let iterate = 0; iterate < OTPLength; iterate++) {             
    self.textboxArray.push({ otp: ko.observable() });
}
```

But how do we get each observable item from this array and set value to each of this. Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: why should it be an array of observables? You should be able to do everything you want by just using observableArray ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider rethinking your choices. Having an observable array with an object with an item called 'otp' that is an observable is really confusing and will be even more when you start using it in the view. Maybe [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is what you're looking for?